# MySQL query to check if this is same product

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, comparison

I'm working on price comparision program for 3 website. Each website can have same product with other websites but product name is not exactly same (EX: "Asus X553MA-XX102H Intel Celeron N2930 4GB 1TB DVDRW 15.6 Windows 8.1" and "Asus X553MA 15.6 Inch Intel Celeron 4GB 1TB Laptop" is one product but the name is not exactly same).

I was crawled data from 3 website to mysql table called crawledproduct(which has 3 columns: sourceurl, productname, price).

Please help me write a MySQL query command to find all same product by product name.

EX: `Select * from crawledproduct where [Similar with 'Asus X553MA 15.6 Inch Intel Celeron 4GB 1TB Laptop']`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If have a standard set of criteria that know will always appear in similar product names, you could use a `like` query to get what you need.

For instance, given your example a above, you can get it like this

```
Select name from crawledproduct 
where name like '%X553MA%'
```

This would work.  Note if you have a lot of data, this can result in very long queries, so you might want to take advantage of MySQL's fulltext searching which runs much faster.  You would need to index `name` as a fulltext field, and then run a query like this:

```
   SELECT name FROM crawledproduct MATCH(name) AGAINST ('X553MA')
```

Edit:

Note, both of these queries assume that `X553MA` will appear in all product names.  You'd have to be careful about how you chose your search term.

Edit:

If you do not know the keyword, you could create a form which would search all three sites.  The user could put in the keyword into this form.

For instance, using the `like` as mentioned, you could have each website's information stored  in a database (assuming you have access to do so) each on a different table.

and search like so:

```
Select tableA.name 
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB
    ON TableB.name = TableA.name
JOIN TableC
    ON TableC.name = TableA.name
WHERE name like '%$search_term%'
```

and you would have $search_term come from  the user.

However if you are looking to actually crawl the site, then SQL is not the tool you want.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But there are various products in this table and i cannot know keyword for each product.

Comment: without knowing what you are searching for, you cannot do this with SQL.  If you can get a list of product names and a list of what they are called on each website, you could then create a link between each website, based on a product id, but you'd have to do all of the work yourself first to identify each of the products names on each website.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the name of the product is given as an input by the user itself or you know the product name which you wanna compare.
You need the 'LIKE' clause in your query. Suppose you want to search by the word 'axus':

```
Select name from crawledproduct 
    where productName like '%axus%'
```

% is called a wildcard. It tells the DBMS that you want to search for this pattern. Suppose you want to search for "axus" in each row in column A:

```
like '%axus' //This means give the rows which have entries in column A ending with axus

like 'axus%' //This means give the rows which have entries in column A starting with axus

like '%axus%' //This means give the rows which have entries in column A which contain the word axus.
```

Ofcourse, you need to enter the search term properly in order to get all the products. If a same product does not have the keyword that you specified, then it won't be displayed in your output. There are several other ways to search for a pattern in your database table. 
You might wanna do a bit of a research on that, because I am a beginner and I don't have much knowledge yet. 
Good luck!
Kudos! :)

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But there are various products in this table and i cannot know keyword for each product.